# Why are there unnamed Cambrian Stages?

Tags: stratigraphy, geochronology

What is it about Stages 2,3,4, and 10 (as well as Series 2) in the Cambrian Period that has left solely them unnamed? Will this be resolved in time, or is it a relic of the historical naming process, and is likely to remain fixed?